# iperf2 total bandwidth sustained by server

Tags: iperf

I'm running a single `iperf2` instance to which multiple TCP clients connect.

Is there a way to make `iperf2` report the total bandwidth sustained by the server (the sum of the individual bandwidths for every client connection)?

Comment: Are your "multiple TCP clients" separate devices, or just multiple copies of IPerf running on a single device?

Comment: @Spiff yes, different IPs, different devices.